# How to solve libx264 not found when building ffmpeg-with-libx264-enabled for android?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, libavcodec, x264, libx264

i am trying build android-ffmpeg-x264 downloaded from git.  Link https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264

After running  ./config_make_everything.sh  i am getting following error

ERROR: libx264 not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.

```
<pre>
Makefile:1: config.mak: No such file or directory
libavutil/Makefile:1: libavutil/../config.mak: No such file or directory
libavutil/../subdir.mak:96: warning: overriding commands for target `libavutil/'
libavutil/../subdir.mak:26: warning: ignoring old commands for target `libavutil/'
libavutil/../subdir.mak:96: warning: overriding commands for target `libavutil/'
libavutil/../subdir.mak:96: warning: ignoring old commands for target `libavutil/'

tests/Makefile:44: /tests/fate.mak: No such file or directory
tests/Makefile:45: /tests/fate2.mak: No such file or directory
tests/Makefile:47: /tests/fate/aac.mak: No such file or directory
tests/Makefile:48: /tests/fate/als.mak: No such file or directory
tests/Makefile:49: /tests/fate/fft.mak: No such file or directory
tests/Makefile:50: /tests/fate/h264.mak: No such file or directory
tests/Makefile:51: /tests/fate/mp3.mak: No such file or directory
tests/Makefile:52: /tests/fate/vorbis.mak: No such file or directory
tests/Makefile:53: /tests/fate/vp8.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/fate/vp8.mak'.  Stop.
</pre>
```

config.log contains

```
<pre>
    ratecontrol.c:(.text+0xa400): undefined reference to `memset'
ratecontrol.c:(.text+0xa41c): undefined reference to `memset'
ratecontrol.c:(.text+0xa448): undefined reference to `__aeabi_l2d'
ratecontrol.c:(.text+0xa49c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ldivmod'
ratecontrol.c:(.text+0xa4a0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_l2d'
ratecontrol.c:(.text+0xa4f8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_idivmod'
ratecontrol.c:(.text+0xa794): undefined reference to `__aeabi_l2d'
../x264/libx264.a(set.o): In function `x264_validate_levels':
set.c:(.text+0x200): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ldivmod'
set.c:(.text+0x334): undefined reference to `__aeabi_idiv'
../x264/libx264.a(set.o): In function `x264_sei_version_write':
set.c:(.text+0xeec): undefined reference to `strlen'
set.c:(.text+0xf10): undefined reference to `memcpy'
set.c:(.text+0xf3c): undefined reference to `sprintf'
set.c:(.text+0xf44): undefined reference to `strlen'
../x264/libx264.a(set.o): In function `scaling_list_write':
set.c:(.text+0x20b0): undefined reference to `memcmp'
set.c:(.text+0x2138): undefined reference to `memcmp'
set.c:(.text+0x2158): undefined reference to `memcmp'
../x264/libx264.a(set.o): In function `x264_pps_write':
set.c:(.text+0x5870): undefined reference to `memcmp'
set.c:(.text+0x5a7c): undefined reference to `memcmp'
../x264/libx264.a(set.o):set.c:(.text+0x5a9c): more undefined references to `memcmp' follow
../x264/libx264.a(macroblock.o): In function `x264_noise_reduction_update':
macroblock.c:(.text+0xe10): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uldivmod'
../x264/libx264.a(macroblock.o): In function `x264_predict_lossless_8x8_chroma':
macroblock.c:(.text+0x3224): undefined reference to `memcpy'
macroblock.c:(.text+0x323c): undefined reference to `memcpy'
../x264/libx264.a(cabac.o): In function `x264_macroblock_write_cabac':
cabac.c:(.text+0x2c58): undefined reference to `__assert2'
cabac.c:(.text+0x2dd8): undefined reference to `__assert2'
cabac.c:(.text+0x2f80): undefined reference to `__assert2'
cabac.c:(.text+0x3020): undefined reference to `__assert2'
../x264/libx264.a(rectangle.o): In function `x264_macroblock_cache_ref_1_1':
rectangle.c:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `__assert2'
../x264/libx264.a(rectangle.o):rectangle.c:(.text+0x210): more undefined references to `__assert2' follow
ERROR: libx264 not found
</pre>
```

1.I am using fedora to build both ffmpeg and x264 
2.NDK r7

Any solution to successfully build the code?

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet confirmed this personally but I believe you can solve this if you downgrade the NDK to r5c. Remember to recreate the toolchain.